# What is the physical meaning of simultaneity if all space-time are zero to both moving and stationary observers?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I do not get the physical meaning for both stationary observer and moving observer got all the space time be zero.

By simultaneity, we know that the time measured by one person is not the same by another person.

What if having a simultaneous event at the same place at the same time?

Then, we have

> x=0, t=0
>
> x'=(x-ut)$\gamma$=0
>
> t'=(t-$\frac{u}{c^2}$x)$\gamma$

So t=t'=x=x'=0, what is the physical meaning in simultaneity?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by *"all space-time are zero to both moving and stationary observers"*. There's no problem with an event at (t=0, x=0) in the unprimed frame having coords (t'=0, x'=0) in the primed frame.

Answer (score 0):

> I presume you mean two events happening at the same place and at the same time?

Well, then the spacetime interval between the two events are zero and it will be zero for all observers.

In relativity, it would usually be treated as just one event, but there is nothing wrong with viewing them as two simultaneous events at the same place and time.